# Need to increment red pixel values in native c++

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

in android with jni i have a cpp code to change or increment red pixel values with the help of bitmap data passed from android

```
Java_com_journaldev_androidjnibasics_MainActivity_sendMyBitmap(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                               jobject bitmap) {

    AndroidBitmapInfo info;
    int ret;
    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info)) < 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (info.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
        return NULL;
    }
    //
    //read pixels of bitmap into native memory :
    //
    void *bitmapPixels;
    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &bitmapPixels)) < 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    uint32_t *src = (uint32_t *) bitmapPixels;
    uint32_t *tempPixels = new uint32_t[info.height * info.width];
    int stride = info.stride;
    int pixelsCount = info.height * info.width;
    int x, y, red, green, blue;

    for (y=0;y<info.height;y++) {


        uint32_t * line = (uint32_t *)bitmapPixels;
        for (x=0;x<info.width;x++) {

            blue = (int) ((line[x] & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
            green = (int)((line[x] & 0x00FF00) >> 8);
            red = (int) (line[x] & 0x0000FF);

            //just set it to all be red for testing
            red = 255;
            green = 0;
            blue = 0;

            //why is the image totally blue??
            line[x] =
                    ((blue<< 16) & 0xFF0000) |
                    ((green << 8) & 0x00FF00) |
                    (red & 0x0000FF);
        }

        bitmapPixels = (char *)bitmapPixels + info.stride;
    }


    memcpy(tempPixels, src, sizeof(uint32_t) * pixelsCount);
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
    //
    //recycle bitmap - using bitmap.recycle()
    //
    jclass bitmapCls = env->GetObjectClass(bitmap);
    jmethodID recycleFunction = env->GetMethodID(bitmapCls, "recycle", "()V");
    if (recycleFunction == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    env->CallVoidMethod(bitmap, recycleFunction);
    //
    //creating a new bitmap to put the pixels into it - using Bitmap Bitmap.createBitmap (int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config) :
    //
    jmethodID createBitmapFunction = env->GetStaticMethodID(bitmapCls, "createBitmap",
                                                            "(IILandroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");
    jstring configName = env->NewStringUTF("ARGB_8888");
    jclass bitmapConfigClass = env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap$Config");
    jmethodID valueOfBitmapConfigFunction = env->GetStaticMethodID(bitmapConfigClass, "valueOf",
                                                                   "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;");
    jobject bitmapConfig = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(bitmapConfigClass,
                                                       valueOfBitmapConfigFunction, configName);
    jobject newBitmap = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(bitmapCls, createBitmapFunction, info.height,
                                                    info.width, bitmapConfig);
    //
    // putting the pixels into the new bitmap:
    //
    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, newBitmap, &bitmapPixels)) < 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    uint32_t *newBitmapPixels = (uint32_t *) bitmapPixels;
    int whereToPut = 0;
    for (int x = info.width - 1; x >= 0; --x)
        for (int y = 0; y < info.height; ++y) {
            uint32_t pixel = tempPixels[info.width * y + x];
            newBitmapPixels[whereToPut++] = pixel;
        }
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, newBitmap);

    delete[] tempPixels;





    return newBitmap;

}
```

Here after this process, the image getting fully transparent or white colour. can anyone hep me out to do this. My aim is to change the value of R (red) pixel in this bitmap data. thanks in advance

Comment: Just trying to think along : ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 looks like you're shifting for ARGB order.

Comment: so may i know what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// header file byte_masks.h

// two constexpr functions that will write out the shift and mask functions at compile time
// from_byte<0> will be the same as (value & 0x000000FF) >> 0;
// from_byte<1> will be the same as (value & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
// from_byte<2> will be the same as (value & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
// from_byte<3> will be the same as (value & 0xFF000000) >> 24;

#pragma once
#include <cstdint>

template<size_t N>
constexpr auto from_byte(std::uint32_t value)
{
    const std::uint32_t shift = 8 * N;
    const std::uint32_t mask = 0xFF << shift;
    std::uint32_t retval{ (value & mask) >> shift };
    return static_cast<std::uint8_t>(retval);
}

// to_byte<1> will be the same as value << 8 etc...
template<size_t N>
constexpr auto to_byte(std::uint8_t value)
{
    const std::uint32_t shift = 8 * N;
    return static_cast<std::uint32_t>(value << shift);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// header file color_t.h

#pragma once
#include <cstdint>

struct color_t
{
    static color_t from_argb(std::uint32_t pixel);
    static color_t from_bgra(std::uint32_t pixel);

    std::uint32_t to_argb_value();
    std::uint32_t to_bgra_value();

    std::uint8_t alpha = 0;
    std::uint8_t red = 0;
    std::uint8_t green = 0;
    std::uint8_t blue = 0;
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// source file color_t.cpp

    #include<color_t.h>
    #include <byte_masks.h>

    // this is basically the logic you used reading the data as ARGB
    // to create a color from an integer value
color_t color_t::from_argb(std::uint32_t pixel)
{
    color_t color{};
    color.alpha = from_byte<3>(pixel);
    color.red = from_byte<2>(pixel);
    color.green = from_byte<1>(pixel);
    color.blue = from_byte<0>(pixel);
    return color;
}

// But your bitmap data has a different order for alpha, red, green, blue!!!
// ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888
color_t color_t::from_bgra(std::uint32_t pixel)
{
    color_t color{};
    color.blue = from_byte<3>(pixel);
    color.green = from_byte<2>(pixel);
    color.red = from_byte<1>(pixel);
    color.alpha = from_byte<0>(pixel);
    return color;
}

std::uint32_t color_t::to_argb_value()
{
    return (to_byte<3>(alpha) | to_byte<2>(red) | to_byte<1>(green) | to_byte<0>(blue));
}

std::uint32_t color_t::to_bgra_value()
{
    return (to_byte<3>(blue) | to_byte<2>(green) | to_byte<1>(red) | to_byte<0>(alpha));
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// my main.cpp, but use the color_t functions from below in your code

#include <cassert>
#include <color_t.h>

int main()
{
    // two lines just to simulate a bit of your code
    std::uint32_t line[]{ 0x00000, 0x11223344 };
    const size_t x = 1;

    // now it's easy to get the color and change it.
    // this will use the blue, green, red alpha order matching your 
    // ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 format.
    auto color = color_t::from_bgra(line[x]);
    color.red = 255;

    // also note that by splitting out code into smaller functions
    // it becomes much easier to read (specially for other people)
    line[x] = color.to_bgra_value();

    assert(to_byte<1>(line[x]) == 255);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. may i know one more thing. how should I use this code in my current code. am a beginner and am not much aware of this. don't feel bad asking you like this

Comment: Hi mariya I update the example. Split the example in three files: byte_mask.h, color_t.h and color_t.cpp. And add them to your project (I don't know what you use to build).
Then include "color_t.h" in your code and modify the lines that do std::uint32_t to color conversion (or back) to use color_t functions. Don't hesitate to ask more

Answer (score 0):

I see several mistakes in your code:

1. You read the bitmap as BGRA_8888 into `tempPixels` and use `tempPixels` as source for a new ARGB_8888 buffer. You should make sure both buffers have the same format OR flip the pixel component order.
2. The incoming bitmap has a stride (=length of a row in bytes) that may not be equal to 4 * width. This means you should multiply `info.height` with `info.stride` instead. Possibly multiplied by 4, I don't know if the stride is documented to be in pixels or in bytes.
3. As I said, the input pixel format is BGRA, but you completely ignore the A component. That makes the output fully transparent. I suggest using a `struct { uint8_t b,g,r,a; } pixel` to disassemble the pixels and manipulate individual elements instead.
4. Finally, is there a good reason you cannot manipulate the incoming Bitmap instead of creating a new one and making two copies?